# Entity Framework 6 migrations with MVC 6 RC 1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a EF 6 Dbcontext and migrations in the separate class library project (data layer), rather than in the main mvc 6 project.
However, when we are trying to call this on the first run of the project

```
context.Database.Initialize(false);
```

We get very strange error message

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not find file
>   'MyProject.Data.resources'.

Stack Trace:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary<String, ResourceSet> localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents) 
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture) 
at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.GetDefaultSchema(DbMigration migration) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<GetHistorySchemas>b__6(<>f__AnonymousType10<String, DbMigration> <>h__TransparentIdentifier4) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0<TSource, TMiddle, TResult>.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator<TSource, TResult>.MoveNext() 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__58<TSource>.MoveNext() 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__58<TSource>.MoveNext() 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__63<TSource>.MoveNext() 
at System.Linq.Buffer<TElement>..ctor(IEnumerable<TElement> source) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ReverseIterator>d__74<TSource>.MoveNext() 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.QueryExists(String contextKey) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.Exists(String contextKey) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.History.HistoryRepository.<GetUpgradeOperations>d__16.MoveNext() 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b() 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) 
at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() 
at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration>.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf<TContext>.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction<TInput>.PerformAction(TInput input) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action<InternalContext> action) 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() 
at System.Data.Entity.Database.Initialize(Boolean force) 
at MyProject.Data.DbHelper.SetupDatabase() in E:\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject.Data\DbHelper.cs:line 29 
at MyProject.Business.Services.DatabaseService.SetupDatabase() in E:\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject.Business\Services\DatabaseService.cs:line 17 
at MyProject.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in E:\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject.Web\Startup.cs:line 61
```

That's very strange. It works when we are trying to set connection string in the Data project's App.config and run update-database from package manager console (but I believe that's because in that case it behaves like a separate project).

Anyone have a good solution to this problem?

P.S. The other issues are not answering to this, because it is a problem with accessing migration in csproj project from xproj project.

Comment: You should probably add a stack trace for this issue and tell, what MyProject.Data.resources file is about. You are probably missing "Copy=Always" setting on some of the files in your data layer library project.

Comment: @raderick - Stack Trace added... There is no any manual resource in that project. It's something that EF 6 is trying to get from configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use Class Library with EF 6.1.3 from Asp.Net 5 MVC 6 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532188/why-cant-i-use-class-library-with-ef-6-1-3-from-asp-net-5-mvc-6-project)

Comment: Decision was to downgrade to mvc 5... unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It's a knowned dnx issue. It's not a migration problem, but a problem about EF6 model in class libraries.

Answer is here : [Entity Framework 7 error : "EntityFramework.Core.resources" is missing (7.0.0-rc1-final)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35147284/solved-entity-framework-7-error-entityframework-core-resources-is-missing)

Add this to your Startup's Configure method :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        //...
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        {
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("") },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("") }
        };

        var invariantCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo(""), new CultureInfo(""));

        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions, invariantCulture);
        //...
    }
```